# Printing index and element of array

Tags: java, arrays

Hey guys I'm really struggling with trying to print my array index and element value, I posted a question a few days ago and got really helpful advice but cannot seem to get this part right at all, I am able to print the 1st index of the array (distance) but not able to print the entire thing without losing the original index value:

```
double minVal = Double.MAX_VALUE;
int minIndex = -1;
for (int i=0, max=distances.length; i<max;i++) {
    if (distances[i] < minVal) {
        minVal = distances[i];
        minIndex = i;
        //Gets the minimum point and minimum distance
    }
}

System.out.println("The Nearest to point K is point: "+minIndex+" with distance "+minVal);
```

Really sorry to keep bringing this matter up but really have tried and cannot get it to work for the life of me any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You code looks like it ought to work

Comment: what does this mean "but not able to print the entire thing without loosing the original index value:"

Comment: _//Gets the minimum point and minimum distance_ If you want to print everything from array then move your `System.out.println( ....)` statement inside `for` loop.

Comment: Ye the code will print out the smallest index and its value however i am trying to print out all the indexes from smallest to largest e.g: The nearest to point K is point 1 with distance 12, The Second nearest to point K is point 4 with distance 13, sorry that i did not make that very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you sort

```
for (int i=0; i<distances.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j<distances.length; j++)
    {
        if (distances[i] > distances[j]) 
        {
             double temp = distances[j];
             distances[j] = distances[i];
             distances[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you merely print

```
for (int i=0; i<distances.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " -> " + distances[i]);
}
```

---

If you want to keep the original indexes, you can do that too.

- the most obvious way would be to have a second paralell array, and sort that along with your original array

example:

```
if (distances[i] < minVal) 
{
    double temp = distances[j];
    int tempindex = indices[j];
    ...
```

- the better way would be to make a class with an index(or more appropriately named, an ID), and a value(which is your double), and sort an array of type Distance.

.

```
 Class Distance
 {
      public int ID;
      public double value;
 }
```

Comment: Simply putting `print` statement inside `if` block will do the job, isn't it?

Comment: @Smit you still have to sort the array, but yeah, if you put the `print` statement inside the outer loop of the selection sort, than yeah, that would work

Comment: If you take a look at very last comment from OP, from that I have deduced this and for that it does not need sorting.,

Comment: @Smit  putting a print statement inside the OP's if statement will only print all the elements in the array in **1** scenario, and that scenario is when the array is already sorted, but in descending order(with the largest element first).  **otherwise**  there will be some values in the array that are not printed.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help its already helped to understand a lot, I tried the top code however the output:                Point[1] Distance:316.0
Point[2] Distance:970.0
Point[3] Distance:32.0
Point[4] Distance:551.0
1 -> 316.0
2 -> 970.0
3 -> 32.0
4 -> 551.0                                                          still isnt doing what i need it to do as i need it to print out each index or ID with the original value in order from smallest value to largest value, even if i were to keep the original ID it isnt sorting the smallest distance from point K.

Comment: @user3004630 I fixed it.  I was still incrementing `i` in my inner loop instead of `j`. It should work now

Comment: Okay so i have cloned the array distances using :               double indices []
              =(double[])distances.clone();                         and have added the code to my if statement:                                                     double tempindex = indices[j];                                indices[j] = indices[i];
indices[i] = tempindex;                                          but does not keep the indexes of the original values so im guessing i have missed something?

Comment: as per the second part of the answer, you can make a second array of **int**, `int indices[]`, and you just fill that array with the indices.  to start with, it will be integers in ascending order `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]`, and any change you make to the array you're sorting, you make to that one too

Comment: Im sorry I cannot quite work this out so i have                   int indices[] = new int[15];
int tempindex = indices[i];
indices[j] = indices[i];
indices[i] = tempindex;                                          but then to print out i have:                                    for (int i=1; i<distances.length; i++) 
      {
        System.out.println(i + " -> " + distances[i]);
        
      }                                                            how do i go about changing what gets printed out instead of just i being printed?

Comment: `System.out.println(indices[i] + " -> " + distances[i]); }`

Comment: it just keeps repeating the index 0 with all the values, i have looked at the int indices and guessing i have done something wrong here?                                                                                int [] indices = new int [15];
                 int tempindex = indices[i];
                 indices[j] = indices[i];
                 indices[i] = tempindex;

Comment: @user3004630  If you don't understand the answer enough to work things like this out yourself, than there is a problem.  which part of the answer do you not understand?

Comment: sorry i have created the int array and placed within the if statement however when i compile all the indexes are set to 0 and the values of the array are repeated many times, i have tried to change the integer array however have had no luck and cannot seem to get it to print the correct index for the corresponding value, my int array:int [] indices = new int [15];  is followed by         int tempindex = indices[i];
    indices[j] = indices[i];
    indices[i] = tempindex;                                         I am guessing i have gone wrong at some point but cannot see where?

Comment: @user3004630 I'm more interested in you understanding the solution to the problem than simply giving you the solution.  What I'm asking is, **Do you understand the logic** of my answer.  If you do not, than please tell me what you do not understand?

Comment: thanks mate i appreciate it, i understand most of it what i dont understand is how the index of the array distance is being used in the indices array in order for it to keep the original index

Comment: @user3004630  you're using that to make a sorted array of indicies.  you declare and completely fill the index array **before** you do any sorting at all.  just fill it with `for(int i=0; i<indices.length; i++){indices[i] = i};`

Comment: @user3004630 every change you make to the distances array, you make to the indices array too.  That way, the original index will continue to be associated with it's original value.

Answer (score -1):

Try change the for loop to `for(int i=0; max = distances.length && i < max; i++){...}`

Comment: `max` is nothing but `array length`. By changing this condition make no difference and `array length` is never changing.