# keep original index of array (continued)

Tags: java

Hey guys thanks for your help previously especially to Sam I am, almost got this working however due to an family emergency had to stop working on it for a while, everything seems to be working except one bit which is keeping the original indicies:

```
int [] indices = new int [15];         
for(int i=0; i<indices.length; i++){indices[i] = i;} 

// Below code used for sorting
for (int i=0; i<distances.length; i++)
{
for(int j = i+1; j<distances.length; j++)
{
    if (distances[i] > distances[j])  
    {
         double temp = distances[j];
        distances[j] = distances[i];
        distances[i] = temp;                                      

         int tempindex = indices[i];
         indices[j] = indices[i];
         indices[i] = tempindex;                                       
    }            
 }       
 }

for (int i=1; i<distances.length; i++) 
{
 System.out.println("Point "+indices[i] + " -> " + distances[i]);
}

}
```

Sam I am did explain how to do it however seem to be having trouble getting the code to display the original index so does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just a little tip: can you post a link to the original question? There are 529935 questions related to java over the course of 5 years making finding the right question difficult.

Comment: Found it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223065/printing-index-and-element-of-array

Comment: you should use a mapping of index and distance, but did you tried holaps suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I've understood your question. But I think there is an idex problem.

Thake a loot to the index you use when you assign tempindex.

```
int tempindex = indices[i];
indices[j] = indices[i];
// tempindex is equal to indeices[i], so this instruction does nothing.
indices[i] = tempindex;
```

Try to change

```
int tempindex = indices[i];
```

To

```
int tempindex = indices[j];
```

Comment: @kai ok. Can't understand the problem.

Comment: sorry i didnt understood. i think you are right. he want to move the indicies in the array, like the distances.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i wanted Kai thanks alot man appreciate it :)